# How is JavaScript .on() method defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, event-handling

In the jQuery library, the function doesn't exist, yet every jQuery object has these essential methods. In another thread, it was stated that .on() belongs to the node API, which confuses me, since it can be used in the front-end and I don't even need to include `const EventEmitter = require('events');` and neither does the jquery.min.js. I just would like to learn about why for example the strings 'click' or 'mouseover' are valid arguments.

Also, the on() method makes extensive use of callback functions. 
For example:
`$('class').on('click', event => {...})`

I would like to understand why it can be passed a lambda function or 'event' as stated above.

Also, some might find the following resource useful, however, it is not really that straightforward and made me come up with more questions than answers:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html

Comment: Various libraries use the word "on" as a name (or part of names) in event handling because of what the word means in ordinary English usage. The jQuery `.on()` has absolutely nothing directly to do with any Node APIs other than the name. The jQuery `.on()` does indeed "exist" in the library source, but the jQuery code is written for efficiency, not readability.

Comment: The Node.JS `.on` and the jQuery `.on` are different. You seem to be mixing up both of them.

Comment: In jQuery the function exists by inheritance essentially if you look at the HTML Dom objects without jQuery they have an "on" method and since jQuery objects represent and inherit from the HTML Dom objects it has the same method

Comment: What do you mean the function doesn't exist in the JQuery library? It's documented [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: So jQuery is inheriting from the HTML Dom not nodejs and since that function has existed in the HTML Dom interface for so long I find it more likely that nodejs chose that format to be stylistically similar to the JavaScript that already existed before nodejs was created

Comment: @Binvention the DOM model defines an [`EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method, not an `on()` method... `on()` is a completely synthetic function, there is absolutely no "inheritance" going on here.

Comment: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.on

Comment: A jquery object doesn't *inherit* from a DOM object in anyway at all. It *wraps* the DOM object, that's why you have to do `$("#id").get(0).id` and not just `$("#id").id`.

Comment: Okay thank you guys so far: As someone who's been writing maybe 30 lines of codes in JS this is a bit mind blowing. I also don't recall event handlers from my highschool times (about 2007) where we programmed with java.

What I conclude:
1) node.js and jQuery both have a .on() method for event handling, yet they are differently implemented.

2) the jQuery method is defined in jQuery.fn.on but not in jquery.min.js and I still have no idea from where my browser fetches the definiton

Comment: @Marcellvs: I don't use JQuery, but "min" generally means "minified": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: @Marcellvs: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-obfuscate-JS-code-like-jquery-min-js

Comment: Okay, jquery.min.js is not readable, I saw that, and I formatted it with vcs, but still the definitions should be the same? Interestingly, the code looks somewhat similar, but there is a lot more to it, than removed whitespace and comments. Even the fact that `var isFunction = function isFunction( obj ) {`is the same as `        `y = function e(t) {` is almost no hieroglyphical to me. 
How can the browser find the function .on(), when in the min.js it is named probably "t" or something similar?

Comment: @Marcellvs: take a look to this document: https://www.keycdn.com/support/uglifyjs

Comment: @Marcellvs: and this one too (mangle section): https://github.com/terser-js/terser/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`on` method registers a handler, which is callback function with specific signature. Once an event is triggered, a handler is called. It receives necessary data as function parameters (commonly `event` object).

jQuery and Node event emitter aren't related in any way, they both have `on` method because it's a conventional way for a method that adds event handlers.

A naive implementation that shows how it works:

```
const emitter = {
  handlers: {},

  on(eventName, handler) {
    if (!this.handlers[eventName])
      this.handlers[eventName] = [];

    this.handlers[eventName].push(handler);
  },

  emit(eventName, data) {
    for (const handler of this.handlers[eventName])
      handler(data);
  }
};

emitter.on('foo', data => console.log(data.text));

emitter.emit('foo', { text: 'Foo event triggered' });
```

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you.